# Highlighting previous SelectedItem in DataGrid when Using MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

When a datagrid item is selected, I'm loading the data into a different XAML view. The user is then allowed to add/change/edit data in that view.

When selecting a new item in the datagrid, before accessing the new item, I'm checking to see if the current item has any data changes. If so, I present a messagebox asking if they want to continue. If they don't want to continue, I return to the current selection. However, the newly selected item is still highlighted. How can I return the highlight to the current item?

The SelectedItem in the view is bound to an ICommand in the ViewModel.

XAML

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridSession" 
        Grid.Column="1" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
        Grid.Row="3"       
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DisplayMemberPath="Identifier"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Sessions}"
        MinHeight="190" 
        PreviewMouseDown="DataGridSession_PreviewMouseDown"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSession, Mode=TwoWay}"
        SelectionMode="Single"
        SelectionUnit="FullRow"
        Style="{DynamicResource SelectorDataGrid}"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        Margin="0, 0, 0, 0">
```

ViewModel

```
private SessionItemViewModel _selectedSession;
    public SessionItemViewModel SelectedSession
    {
        get { return _selectedSession; }
        set
        {
            _selectedSession = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            if(_selectedSession != null)
            {
                _eventAggregator.GetEvent<OpenSessionViewEvent>()
                    .Publish(SelectedSession.SessionId);
            }
        }
    }
```

MainViewModel

```
 private async void OnOpenSessionView(long sessionId)
    {
        if (SessionViewModel != null && SessionViewModel.HasChanges)
        {
            var result = _messageDialogService.ShowOkCancelDialog("Changes made to this Session will be lost. Do you still want to leave this Session?", "Question");

            if (result == MessageDialogResult.No)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        SessionViewModel = _sessionViewModelCreator();
        await SessionViewModel.LoadSessionAsync(sessionId);
    }
```

Comment: Please can you share some relevant code. Such as the ViewModel properties for SelectedItem and the CurrentlyEditingItem. The Bindings in the XAML would also be useful.

Comment: Anyone? It doesn't have to maintain MVVM standards.